# Как одновременно использовать несколько 3g модемов на 1 компьютере?

Tags: proxy, модемы, 3g

Есть ПК и 4 usb порта, один белый ip. Можно ли одновременно запустить четыре 3g модема, получив 4 сетевых устройства (виртуальных) и на каждом разный ip? Можно ли потом сделать из этого всего прокси-сервер, к которому будут подключатся по белому ip и будет 4 разных порта(для каждого сетевого устройства)?

Или нужно ставить отдельно сетевую карту для каждого usb-модема?

Comment: Можно 1,2,3,4, пять портов. Сколько влезет

Comment: сетевые устройства будут автоматически создаваться или как? Как одновременно выходить в интернет с них, используя разные порты?

Comment: делают как-то. надо у гугля спросить. или ждать пока матёрый сетевик-затейник сюда не заглянет.

Comment: Не чего чего понятно, что

Comment: 1. Подключить к ПК 10 модемов 

2.Получить 10 айпи 

3. Сделать 10 прокси

4. Раздать 10 прокси

реально ли так сделать? или имея только одну сетевую карту можно получить 1 ip от модема и сделать прокси только из него?

Comment: Делается один прокси на всех. Сложность в том, чтобы настроить маршрутизацию. Поищите в гугле вопросы подключения к двум и более провайдерам интернета, балансировка трафика между провайдерами, Ну и конечно ничто не мешает сделать 10 адресов у прокси на каждый модем. Это совсем элементарно. Есть вариант поделить пользователей по маске ип-адреса в рамках одного прокси.

Comment: в этом и сложность. Нужно "каждый порт прокси" пускать через другого провайдера и трафик должен идти одновременно в 10 потоков...

Comment: Хотите объединить 10 модемов в один толстый быстрый канал? Забудьте. Это невозможно. Для этого надо, что бы на другой стороне их кто-то объединил. Даже если они от одного оператора сотовой связи, никто этого делать не будет. Самостоятельно потоки со всех модемов можно собрать на каком-нибудь внешнем сервере( например взять в аренду VPS). И через этот внешний сервер пускать дальше в интернет. Теоретически это возможно. Насчёт практики не знаю.

Comment: нет, я хочу 10 модемов впихнуть в ноут, создать 10 отдельных каналов. Потом поднять прокси- сервер на ноуте и выступать в качестве прокси-сервера. Об одном канале речи нету.